# Python Flask using jinja in Javascript

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my Route.py

```
 def route_template(template):
        x = 3
        return render_template("home/" + template, segment=segment,x=x)
```

i want to show x in Javascript

```
var graph = Morris.Donut({
        
        element: 'morris-donut-chart',
        data: [{
                value: 100, # here want to add jinja
                label: 'Data 1'
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Data 1'
            },
           
        ],
    });
```

i try this but not working  `value: {{X}},` .. what is best way to add jinja in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code and let me know if it is ok.

```
xdata = JSON.parse({{ x | tojson }})
var graph = Morris.Donut({
        
        element: 'morris-donut-chart',
        data: [{
                value: xdata,
                label: 'Data 1'
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Data 1'
            },
           
        ],
    });
```

Source: https://medium.com/@crawftv/javascript-jinja-flask-b0ebfdb406b3

Regards,

Hamid